# How to just get the data using CRUD POST method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have developed Small Spring boot Rest api app. I can able to get the data or create new record and search with paging and sorting.

Now i'm looking for provide input data in body to get the data instead of providing in URL with GET method. Is this method also default function ? Please advise.

```
public interface CodeTextRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CodeText, Long> { 
}
```

How to write POST method to just get the data ?

```
http://localhost:8080/api/code

method : POST
{
"code":1
}
```

Comment: could you please be more clear ...what actually you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. I want to get the data using below method http://localhost:8080/api/code

method : POST
{
"code":1
}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a `controller` that will get the a model as body parameter (`{ "code": 1 }`) in a `POST` method and then do something with it.

To do that, you can create a controller that looks like the following (I inserted pseudo-code as an example):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/code")
public class CodeTextController {

    private CodeTextRepository codeTextRepository;

    // constructor injection
    public CodeTextController(CodeTextRepository codeTextRepository) {
        this.codeTextRepository = codeTextRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public CodeText postCodeText(@RequestBody CodeTextRequest codeTextRequest) {
        // some code to get from the DB
        return codeText;
    }

}

public class CodeTextRequest {
    private int code;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! Already i have data in the database. So i'm doing just read only here. So i want to pull the data from database using POST method instead of GET method.

Comment: @user2848031 i edited the answer to match what you said, its pretty much the same just doing fetch instead of save, the way to create a POST mapping in a controller is still as I mentioned, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `Accept` header to the request, like 
`accept: application/json`

Spring Data-Rest will return the body after a `POST` request if either the `returnBodyOnCreate` flag was explicitly set to true in the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` OR if the flag was NOT set AND the request has an `Accept` header.

You can set the flag directly during configuration, or you can set it via the application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.returnBodyOnCreate = true
```

you can also set it separately for update:

```
spring.data.rest.returnBodyOnUpdate = true
```

---- edit

Maybe I misunderstood your question. If you simply want to GET an existing data using POST method, then DO NOT DO IT AT ALL! That's not a REST API any more. There must be some reason you want to do it, but you should try do resolve that original problem instead in another way!